# Reference component itself in styled-components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, styled-components

I have a component like this below. Can I somehow reference to the `Step` component itself? I mean something like `${this}`. I tried to do `${Step}`, but it gives me error: `was used before it was defined`.

```
const Step = styled.i`
  height: 25px;
  width: 14px;
  background-color: grey;

  :hover ~ ${this}, :hover {
    background: blue;
  }
`;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `&:hover` in this case:

```
&:hover ~ &, &:hover {
  background: blue;
}
```

Comment: but i need also this part ```:hover ~ ${this}```

Comment: ok, could you show an example what is the aim exactly here (maybe include HTML code also in OP)?

Comment: Does it `&:hover ~ &` work for you?

Comment: ooh thank You Sajib Khan thats it! So ```&``` means ```self```, thank You.